# Travelling with B1 during L1b review

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have B1 visitor US visa. Recently my attorney has sent my L1b petition to USCIS. I’m going to get working visa.

**Question: Can I visit US with my B1 visa during my L1b petition review?** Having a conference soon

Is there a chance that it can be an issue on border control?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Shouldn't be any issues if you're traveling to a conference and can show that.